# How to glue stones and shells to burlap-covered wood?

Tags: adhesives, glass, fabric

I bought a oval, finished piece of wood, then I covered it with burlap. My issue now is which kind of glue should I use to hold my glass stones and shells on it?

I have my glue gun , this what I used to apply my burlap (along with some normal Staples). The glass pieces are the type we all see in any crafts no-show. I bought a bag of them, so you know what I'm describing. The shells are from any beach from L.A./Florida. No doubt the glass is going to be my challenge due to there weight, and being round. Roundness doesn't leave much area to attach glue or anything.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with all different types of glass on a daily basis for over 20 years, stained, frosted, fused, etc. I create mosaic art pieces using all sorts of different backings. For example: Glass on glass, glass on wood, glass on metal, glass on ceramic, glass on plastic, and the piece I'm working  on now is glass on egg shells. Yes, glass on blown out egg shells.

Over the years  I have tried everything from Elmer's school glue to contact cement, to hot glue guns and I have found that the best adhesive to attach any type of glass to any surface is "Weldbond". It is the strongest, weather and water proof, a little goes a long way, dries clear glue. And best of all it's inexpensive. You can find it in any craft store for around $8.0o. I swear by it, I wont use anything else my glass pieces. I promise you wont be disappointed. Here are a few links, check it out for yourself.

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Weldbond-All-Purpose-Glue/47657022

[https://www.amazon.com/Weldbond-8-50160-Universal-Adhesive-5-4/dp/B00P94NRDE/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1502264340&sr=8-3&keywords=weldbond+glue+mosaic+adhesive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P94NRDE)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why you wouldn't just try hot glue on these. Yes, we are talking about non-mated surfaces but that should not be an issue.

Hot glue sticks are more than just the one you would find at a discount outlet. Those ones themselves are perfectly fine for basic crafts but know that they make ones more suited for other applications. An off the cuff example / non-specific example would be [these](http://www.gorillatough.com/gorilla-hot-glue-sticks) which are good for bonding to multiple materials or even [these](https://www.hotmelt.com/products/surebonder-739-high-strength-glue-sticks) which claim to be used in auto body work.

You don't *need* to use these "high end" sticks. I was pointing them out to show that hot glue should be a contender.

**Experiment!** Should not be too hard to grab some scrap wood and left over burlap to try some of your shells and glass to see how it will hold up.